# Add buttons to UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, button, uiscrollview

I want them to be shown on the screen 4 at a time so I'm thinking about creating a UIScrollview for that and adding a subview with the buttons on it. How can I add let's say about 20 buttons since I can't have them all on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it your button in array.
Something like this: (just a snippet)

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

    UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 75);
    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i; 

    [scrollView addSubview:button];

// If you want to show only 4 buttons, just tweak it here. You can do this method in anyway you like

    if (column == 4) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else {
        column++;
    }

}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer i'm kind of a newbie and my question is how do i add the buttons array?

Comment: just instantiate it in your header and implement it in your m file. I have use this code so its working.